# icons in PyQt not showing properly

Tags: python, icons, pyqt4, system-tray

I have developed an app with system Tray having menu in Python 2.6.4 and PyQt4.

Every client system has python installed locally, and accessing PyQt4 from network location.

I set SystemTray and required icons for menu items as below.
App folder has `icons` folder from where i am using. so i used `os.getcwd()`

i kept this app folder in a network so that everyone can access.

```
self.mnuItem_1 = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(r'%s\icons\icon1.ico' % (os.getcwd())), "Menu Item 1", self)
self.mnuItem_2 = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(r'%s\icons\icon1.ico' % (os.getcwd())), "Menu Item 1", self)

self.trayIconMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.mnuItem_1)
self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.mnuItem_2)
self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(self)
self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)
TrayIcon = (r'%s\ShowTime_Addons\Media\showtimeIcon.ico' % (os.getcwd()))
self.trayIcon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(TrayIcon))
self.trayIcon.setToolTip('Showtime')
self.trayIcon.show()
```

In some systems i could able to see the icons, but in some systems icons are not shown.

For testing i placed .png and used and it worked.

```
self.mnuItem_1 = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(r'%s\icons\icon1.png' % (os.getcwd())), "Menu Item 1", self)
self.mnuItem_2 = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(r'%s\icons\icon1.png' % (os.getcwd())), "Menu Item 1", self)
```

So came to an understanding that the issue is not with the path but something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution for this scenario

One approach is to set the paths in `qt.config` file and place this in the location of your executable.(In my case its C:\Python26)

As i discribed in my Question that i am accessing PyQt4 from Network Location say `\\somesystem\Share\PyQt4`

We will find a `qt.config` file in `\\somesystem\Share\PyQt4`
Take it and put this below lines in `qt.conf`

```
[Paths]
Prefix = //somesystem/Share/PyQt4
Binaries = //somesystem/Share/PyQt4
```

Everything works fine, even sqldrivers will be loaded. No Need of using `app.addLibraryPath`

Answer (score 0):

No sure this is the solution, but try to not use [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) which gives you the current working directory and it might differ from your application directory. To determine application directory, use:

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then use `base_dir` instead of `os.getcwd()` or do:

```
os.chdir(base_dir)
```